# Install and configure new php version on Mac Catalina

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

When i got mac, it had already installed php 7.3. I installed new version of php with Brew to `/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.9/bin/php` and edited `~/bash_profile`, where i added

```
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.9/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.9/sbin:$PATH"
```

then did `source .bash_profile`. It worked for the current terminal window, but other terminal windows are still on older PHP version `/usr/bin/php`, even after restart. Even plugin in PhpStorm claims that php version is older. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

1. `brew unlink php@7.3`
2. `brew link php@7.4 --force --overwrite`
3. `brew services start php@7.4`

Comment: sadly, as first installation of php was not done with Brew, unlinking with Brew has no effect.

Comment: In that case `brew upgrade php` and then `brew unlink php && brew link --overwrite php@7.4` may help.